# Pyspark dataframe: Counting of unique values in a column, independently co-ocurring with values in other columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame comprising billions of predictions of interactions between two types of molecules, Regulators and Targets (there is no overlap between these) as obtained from various Sources. I need to add a column
containing number resources that predict at least one interaction for the given 'Regulator' and given 'Target'.

In other words, for each pair of 'Regulator' and 'Target' I am trying to obtain number of Sources containing value of 'Regulator' and 'Target', even if not paired within one interaction.

Example:

```python
+---------+------+------+
|Regulator|Target|Source|
+---------+------+------+
|        m|     A|     x|
|        m|     B|     x|
|        m|     C|     z|
|        n|     A|     y|
|        n|     C|     x|
|        n|     C|     z|
+---------+------+------+
```

What I want to obtain is this:

```python
+---------+------+------+----------+
|Regulator|Target|Source|No.sources|
+---------+------+------+----------+
|        m|     A|     x|         1|
|        m|     B|     x|         1|
|        m|     C|     z|         2|
|        n|     A|     y|         2|
|        n|     C|     x|         2|
|        n|     C|     z|         2|
+---------+------+------+----------+
```

Further explanation:

First Row `(m, A, x)`:

- Interactions involving m are predicted by sources x and z.
- Interactions involving A are predicted by sources x and y.
- Overlap of these is x, therefore No.sources equals 1.

Second Row `(m, B, x)`:

- Interactions involving m are predicted by sources x and z.
- Interactions involving B are predicted by source x only.
- Overlap of these is x, therefore No.sources equals 1.

Third Row `(m, C, z)`:

- Interactions involving m are predicted by x and z
- Interactions involving C are predicted by sources x and z.
- Overlap of these is x, z, therefore No.sources equals 2.

Comment: What is your question? Also, what have you tried so far? Please see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to approach this problem. For each row, create 2 new columns:

- Column `'RS'`: The set of sources for the `'Regulator'`
- Column `'TS'`: The set of sources for the `'Target'`

Then your desired output is the length of the intersection of these sets.

Consider the following example:

**Create DataFrame**

```
from pyspark.sql Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
cols = ["Regulator", "Target", "Source"]
data = [
    ('m', 'A', 'x'),
    ('m', 'B', 'x'),
    ('m', 'C', 'z'),
    ('n', 'A', 'y'),
    ('n', 'C', 'x'),
    ('n', 'C', 'z')
]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, cols)
```

**Create new columns**

Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set) and [`pyspark.sql.Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.Window) to calculate the distinct values for the `'Source'` column:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    'RS',
    f.collect_set(f.col('Source')).over(Window.partitionBy('Regulator'))
)

df = df.withColumn(
    'TS',
    f.collect_set(f.col('Source')).over(Window.partitionBy('Target'))
)
df.sort('Regulator', 'Target', 'Source').show()
#+---------+------+------+------+---------+
#|Regulator|Target|Source|    TS|       RS|
#+---------+------+------+------+---------+
#|        m|     A|     x|[y, x]|   [z, x]|
#|        m|     B|     x|   [x]|   [z, x]|
#|        m|     C|     z|[z, x]|   [z, x]|
#|        n|     A|     y|[y, x]|[y, z, x]|
#|        n|     C|     x|[z, x]|[y, z, x]|
#|        n|     C|     z|[z, x]|[y, z, x]|
#+---------+------+------+------+---------+
```

**Compute the length of the intersection**

Define a `udf` to return the length of the intersection of two sets, and use this to compute the `'No_sources'` column. (Note, I used `_` instead of `.` in the column name because it makes it easier to use `select()`.)

```
intersection_length_udf = f.udf(lambda u, v: len(set(u) & set(v)), IntegerType())

df = df.withColumn('No_sources', intersection_length_udf(f.col('TS'), f.col('RS')))

df.select('Regulator', 'Target', 'Source', 'No_sources')\
    .sort('Regulator', 'Target', 'Source')\
    .show()
#+---------+------+------+----------+
#|Regulator|Target|Source|No_sources|
#+---------+------+------+----------+
#|        m|     A|     x|         1|
#|        m|     B|     x|         1|
#|        m|     C|     z|         2|
#|        n|     A|     y|         2|
#|        n|     C|     x|         2|
#|        n|     C|     z|         2|
#+---------+------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.